# Excel D&D Character sheet for 2nd edition

Tags: automation

I am trying to set up the stat block so that when you enter the value of your stat, what those values mean auto populate. I'll give an example.

[Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6017.png)

I want to be able to put 3-25 in one cell, and have the other cells on the same line populate the proper values listed on the same line.

I was looking at IF, IFS, and IF(OR but it continued to come back invalid or error